# Snapshot for different SQL Server Version

Tags: sql-server, database, copy, snapshot

Can I create a snapshot from SQL Server 2012 on a SQL Server 2008 R2 Server? 
The goal is to build reporting and queries without locking the live database.
I need only a DB copy (Getdate()-1)

Comment: create a copy only backup and restore it to somewhere not live.

Comment: Are you looking for a copy of the engine or the data? If you need a copy of the data, you can create a 'backup' of live data and 'restore' it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, the SQL Server 2012 snapshot has specific SQL Server 2012 features in it that are not compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2. These are incompatibilities that you will not see. They are deep in the SQL Server engine. You cannot do this.

It's a similar concept to trying to restore a SQL Server 2012 database backup to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. The higher database version cannot backstep to a lower version.

You need to use a SQL Server of the same level or higher (I believe or higher) for your snapshot server.